# Java FX CSS @import path issue

Tags: css, javafx

In `Java8_31` I imported different `CSS` files like that in my `main.css`:

```
@import "style/common/test1.css";
@import "style/common/test2.css";
```

All files were in the package `style/common` and it worked great.

Now with the build `Java8_40` I did the same thing, but I get the following error message:

> Could not find stylesheet:
>   file:/mypath/../style/common/style/common/test2.css
>   com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser handleImport

All my styles from the `CSS` file `test1.css` are working. What I was curious about was the fact that my path style/common is showing up two times.

So I tried to change my imports to the following:

```
@import "style/common/test1.css";
@import "test2.css";
```

With these imports, both styles of the file `test1` and the file `test2` are working. But both files are still in the same package.

Whats happening here? Is there a known issue about the @import and probably a problem in the CSSParser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually is a known issue:

https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40346

There is a temporary fix available and the issue should be fixed in the next build Java8_u60.

The temporary fix can be made in the `CSSParser` class. Link to the git diff:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/rev/839912277bf0

If you dont want to try the fix or wait for u60, just add all css files to the same folder and import it like that (**temporary solution!**):

```
@import "css/test1.css";
@import "test2.css";
@import "test3.css";
@import "testX.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just contributing to the discussion (not directly to your question):
You don't have to explicitly set the full .css file path. All you need is to specify the .css folder and the file name:

Original path:

```
@import "css/nodes/path/CssFile.css";
```

Full path without folder specification:

```
@import "../../path/CssFile.css";
```

Both work the same. Notice that, in the second example, "../" refers to the path level, not the specific folder name.

So in your case, that would be

```
@import "../common/test1.css";
```